# Adding an "Overall" row that ignores by=x when creating data.frame with data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am creating data.frames that summarize columns by different time periods (day of week, time of day, etc) using data.table.

Using by=x, it is obviously quite easy to have, say, the average sales for each day output.  But, I would *also* like the first row to contain the overall sales averages for each product.

So, for example:

```
   DayofWeek    Sales
    Sunday  -0.32632766
    Sunday  -1.39525094
    Sunday  -0.17669726
    Sunday  0.85023421
    Sunday  0.86486582
    Monday  -0.09989301
    Monday  0.76727639
    Monday  -1.67428010
    Tuesday 0.07731930
    Tuesday -0.49833578
    Tuesday -1.30299674
    Tuesday 0.15315193
```

(Here's the dput():

```
structure(list(DayofWeek = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(-0.326327663381262, 
-1.39525093919452, -0.176697258416924, 0.850234206155951, 0.864865815846249, 
-0.0998930060078245, 0.767276394000856, -1.67428009516407, 0.0773192989619049, 
-0.49833577988136, -1.30299673837641, 0.153151927466779, -0.166978329772809, 
-0.365253835027482, -0.59213504129638, -0.637757052094623, 0.296006778141631, 
-0.561833927961962, 0.279092660752442, 1.0474353590513, 1.72519764838123, 
0.343084207813727, 2.00191818865667)), .Names = c("DayofWeek", 
"Sales"), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can do this

```
mysample.dt<-as.data.table(sample)

mysales.day<-mysample.dt[,list(MeanSales=mean(Sales)),by=DayofWeek]
```

to get this

```
    DayofWeek   MeanSales
    Sunday      -0.03663517
    Monday      -0.33563224
    Tuesday     -0.39271532
    Wednesday   -0.26611608
    Thursday    -0.31129511
    Friday      -0.14137063
    Saturday    1.27940885
```

and then I can just run the above without the by=x to produce one for the overall mean, then just combine those two data.frames together.

However, is there a way to do this within my original argument?

So that the output is:

```
DayofWeek   MeanSales
Overall     0.02642795
Sunday      -0.03663517
Monday      -0.33563224
Tuesday     -0.39271532
Wednesday   -0.26611608
Thursday    -0.31129511
Friday      -0.14137063
Saturday    1.27940885
```

without having to create it in two steps?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in one step.

Comment: Wow, I think that may be the first time you've told me something couldn't be done. :)

It didn't seem like it could- I couldn't foresee a way to get the by=x ignored temporarily, which is what would have to happen.

Is data.table my best method for this, you think?

Comment: Well, of course you can wrap both steps in one function, but calculating groupwise means and an overall mean need different algorithms, which means you need two steps.

Comment: You can use `reshape2:::dcast` for now as follows: `reshape2:::dcast(dt, DayofWeek ~ ., value.var="Sales", margins=TRUE, fun=mean)` if you absolutely need to avoid 2 steps. It'll be slow on big data though. `dcast.data.table` doesn't have `margins` argument yet. When it's done, this'll be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this qualifies as one-step solution.

```
rbind(mysample.dt[, list(DayofWeek = "Overall", MeanSales = mean(Sales))],
      mysample.dt[, list(MeanSales = mean(Sales)), by = DayofWeek])
```